# Python package not installing dependency with python3

Tags: python-3.x, package

I've created a reusable component (package) in Python but I'm having trouble using it with `python3`. My package uses a 3rd party library called [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) like so, in one of my files `core.py`:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import requests
import math
import time
import csv
import os
...
```

Here is my `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
  name = 'my_package',
  packages = ['my_package'],
  version = '0.1.dev4',
  keywords = [ ... ],
  install_requires=[
    'requests',
    'python-dateutil'
  ],
  classifiers = [],
  ...etc
)
```

After installing my package on my system, I'm running into this error after starting `python3`:

```
>>> import my_package
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/matthew/Desktop/my_package/my_package/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from my_package.core import Class
  File "/Users/matthew/Desktop/my_package/my_package/core.py", line 5, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

The requests module doesn't seem to be accessible by my package, why?

Comment: What is the exact your version of Python? Requests says that it supports 3.4 3.5 and 3.6

Comment: Using 3.6.1. Weird, I made some changes and it seems to work fine now...